# Deduplicating messages when using Rebus

Tags: rebus

I have the logic of message processing is not idempotent. So before executing it I have each incoming message to check for duplicates through a special database table that long.

In the case of RabbitMQ, example, if a message is delivered to a consumer and then requeued then RabbitMQ will set the "redelivered" flag on it when it is delivered again. https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html#consumer

Is there a way to know what rebus sent the message again after a failed attempt or need to check every message on duplicate?

If this is not possible, as usually quickly and reliably deduplicate messages, without using a database?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to know what rebus sent the message again after a failed attempt or need to check every message on duplicate?

There's no general way to detect a redelivered message with Rebus.

Rebus' RabbitMQ transport *could* have had the ability to pass the "redelivered" flag on to the consumer as a special header, but it doesn't (at least not at the moment).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Here "https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Sagas/Idempotent/IdempotentSagaIncomingStep.cs" there is a line "idempotencyData.MarkMessageAsHandled(messageId);" but it is not clear, these data remain in the dynamic memory or is it saved to disk... Perhaps, instead of the usual message is to use IdempotentSaga for  deduplication of messages or IdempotentSaga not suitable for deduplication?

Comment: `IdempotentSaga` can certainly be used for deduplication, but it has the caveat that the deduplication works only for the saga data, ensuring that the saga always processes each message exactly once. Outgoing messages (sent by the saga) can still potentially be sent multiple times in the event of an error.